# Show that $s(1)=1$, $s(n)=s(n-1)+lcm[n,s(n-1)]+n=(n+1)!-1$, for $n\ge2$

Tags: recurrence-relations, factorial

A recurrence relation;lcm(lowest common multiple) links to the n! Factorial.

Let $s(1)=1$

$s(n)=s(n-1)+lcm[n,s(n-1)]+n$, for $n\ge2$

$s(n)=(n+1)!-1$

I try:

I have no idea where to start to tackle this problem, but at least show that it is work.

$s(2)=1+lcm[2,1]+2=5$,  $s(2)=3!-1=5$

$s(3)=5+lcm[3,5]+3=23$,  $s(3)=4!-1=23$

$s(4)=23+lcm[4,23]+4=119$,  $s(4)=5!-1=119$

$s(5)=119+lcm[5,119]+5=719$, $s(5)=6!-1=719$

And so on...

Comment: I am not understanding what you want to do?

Comment: We are supposed to prove that s(n) = (n+1)!-1

Comment: i am going to remove this for now and rewrite it again